# Return a StringContent to client to show a message

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have a rest service, and I must do a get that can return one or zero objects.. Here the object I return if I find it:

```
public class FollowXMessage
{
    public string UploadFolder { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public int CustomerType{ get; set; }
}
```

If I find an object I can return correctly it to the client... If I do not find anything I would like to return a message that advice the user that nothing has been found:

```
if (found)
{
    ...
    return Ok(result); //result is FollowXMessage
}
else if (!found)
{
    return Ok(new StringContent("Nothing Found", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"));
}

//In all other cases there has been raised an exception
return BadRequest("Some errors");
```

Client side I thought to manage the result in this way:

```
var successCallback = function (response)
{
    if(typeof response == "string")
        //show message
    else
        //do something             
};
```

The problem is that I never receive a string... If no object is returned I receive this response:

[image]

Where is my message "Nothing Found"?

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't return OK. You should return a 404 Not Found. That's what it's for. The data of the response is in `response.data`. Not in `response`. `response`will never be of type string: it's an HTTP response, containing data, headers, status and config.

Comment: but if i return a 404 Not Found,angular manage it as en error... If I do not find anything, it's not an error

Comment: It's as easy to pass an error callback and test for status==404 than testing the type and text of the response. Respect the HTTP semantics: when a resource doesn't exist, the appropriate respoonse status is 404, not 200.

Comment: thank you, i am thinking, and yes... your approach is surely the best...